# What does this expression do: (x, y) = (y, x % y)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable-unpacking

I see below code but do not know what does it do.

```
(x, y) = (y, x % y)
```

At the beginning I thought it does below:

```
x=y
y=x%y
```

But I noticed I am not right.
Can someone explain what  `(x, y) = (y, x % y)` does?

Comment: FWIW, the parentheses are not needed. This is equivalent: `x, y = y, x % y`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called tuple assignment/unpacking, and to reproduce it linearly, you need a temporary location to store the value of `x`.

It is more equivalent to:

```py
temp=x
x=y
y=temp%y
```

Answer (score 4):

You're right, it does what you think it does. `x` is assigned the value of `y` and `y` is assigned the value of `x%y`

Example:

```
>>> x=5
>>> y=10
>>> (x, y) = (y, x % y)
>>> x
10
>>> y
5
>>>
```

`x` becomes `10` (i.e., the value of `y`)
and `y` becomes `x%y= 5%10 =5`

Answer (score 3):

It does this:

```
t1 = y
t2 = x % y
x = t1
y = t2
del t1, t2
```

except that the variables `t1` and `t2` never actually exist. In other words, it computes the new values to assign to both `x` and `y` based on their *old* values, and changes both at once.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have the exact terminology here.

`(x, y) = (y, x % y)` is doing `x=y, y=x%y` and the same time. If you are running this two lines in sequence, you are pass the value of y to x the do the divide.